# Castle Windsor: Register by Convention with Named part

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Windsor as my DI container. I registered my service specifying a name:

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyService>().Named("MyService"));
```

The problem is that I have a lot of services in my system and I'm tired of register each one of them. how can I do this by convention without loosing the `Named` part? (I don't mind calling my services with the same name as the class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following to register all services deriving from some base/interface and then configure their name:

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                          .BasedOn<IService>()
                          .Configure(c => c.Named(c.Implementation.Name)));
```

For the following example:

```
public interface IService { }
public class Service1 : IService { }
public class Service2 : IService { }
public class Service3 : IService { }
public class Service4 : IService { }
public class Service5 : IService { }
public class Service6 : IService { }
```

Output was:

[image]

---

There are additional ways for selecting which classes to register. See more [in documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md)

Comment: oh, yes! Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @eitanby - great to hear :) glad to help

Comment: @eitanby - please consider marking question as solved (it is not a must but it helps future people know that it solved the problem)